# Introductory books on Complex Geometry for Theoretical Physics audience

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, book-recommendation, complex-geometry

I am looking for some good introductory books on Complex Geometry for Theoretical Physics audience.

My background is General Relativity and Riemannian geometry. I am looking for a book with proper examples. Thanks in advance.